# How to darken background when iframe is opened?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, html

I found an excellent tutorial online in which the opening of a CSS box creates a "blanket" layer in the background.

http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html
^Just click "Click Here To Open The Pop Up"

However, I can't get the same effect to work with iFrames. What happens is the blanket layer goes over the iFrame and the background of the page.

Any suggestions as to how this can be done?

Edit:

Ok so I use a script to create an iframe based on the link.

So would I just add z-index in after height?

Comment: Post your css, the z-index property of your blanket layer is higher then your iframe

Comment: FYI those are called modals or modal dialogs.

Comment: place the iFrame in a container div that you give a specific z-index that's above the z-index of the overlay.  You will most likely need to use absolute positioning too, don't forget. (i.e. relative position for the container's container - then absolute for the container...  if you follow...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is pretty much what shadowbox does, its pretty easy to add too and is fully stylable.
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: by the way, you can also use it for iframes.

Comment: The link provided is for a Japanese Hair Tonic promotion.